# Query to bring member without any active product

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called "Contact" where I have ID and Status of the contact , then I have another table called "Product" where I have the contact ID, product status and ProductID. I'm trying to find contacts which doesn't have any active product. How do I do that. I have used a query below ,

```
Select c.ID
from Contact c
where c.id not in (select p.contactid from product p
                   where p.product_status='Active')
```

but i'm also getting both ID 1234 and 1223. Where in theory I should only get 1223. How do I tweak my script to bring contacts which doesn't have any active product.

Contact table

[image: Contact Table]

Product Table

[image: Product table]

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/EdRCvV7O, only 1223 returned.

Comment: Your query works fine. If you see different results, you either have different data than you show here or a different query ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses, with the condition is that the number of products with status *ACTIVE* must be 0 :

```
SELECT c.ID
FROM Contact c
INNER JOIN Product p ON c.ID = p.Contact_ID
GROUP BY c.ID
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Product_Status = 'Active' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Comment: Not sure if that's in OP's usecase, but this won't return any contacts that don't have any products at all ....

Comment: Consider a switch to `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: If the OP would like to include contacts that do not have any products, then `LEFT JOIN` should be used in this case

Comment: A simpler way may be doing a `LEFT JOIN on (c.ID = p.Contact_ID and p.product_status='Active')` and doing a `WHERE p.pcontact_id is null` instead of the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`.

Comment: Thank's this works , I have products on all the contacts, it could be in either active or inactive status

Comment: Same result as OP's original query... https://dbfiddle.uk/9m9L9yIu